# Kafka oauth 2.0 in NiFi

Tags: apache-kafka, oauth-2.0, apache-nifi

I found how to do OAuth 2.0 to Kafka.

I can configure kafka and create secured topic. In tutorial considered console consumer and producer:

```
./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9093 --topic oauth2-demo-topic --producer.config ./config/sasl-oauth2-producerapp-config.properties
```

sasl-oauth2-producerapp-config.properties:

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=OAUTHBEARER
sasl.login.callback.handler.class=com.oauth2.security.oauthbearer.OAuthAuthenticateLoginCallbackHandler
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required OAUTH_LOGIN_SERVER=<OAuth-server-url> OAUTH_LOGIN_ENDPOINT='/oauth2/default/v1/token' OAUTH_LOGIN_GRANT_TYPE=client_credentials OAUTH_LOGIN_SCOPE=kafka OAUTH_AUTHORIZATION='Basic <encoded-producer-clientId:clientsecret>' OAUTH_INTROSPECT_SERVER=<OAuth-server-url> OAUTH_INTROSPECT_ENDPOINT='/oauth2/default/v1/introspect' OAUTH_INTROSPECT_AUTHORIZATION='Basic <encoded-producer-clientId:clientsecret>';
```

for consumer is similar

Does it possible to add this feature to  Kafka producer and consumer processors in NiFi? I didn't find where I can enter path to sasl-oauth2-producerapp-config.properties or this properties direct to processors parameters

Comment: You may check special identifier info from NiFi connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem doesn't solve yet. Look https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7421